# Magmi redirect to main Magento folder

Tags: php, magento, magmi

Whenever I access any php file in the `magmi` folder, it will redirect to main Magento root directory with a 404 Error. Please help me to solve this issue.

Note, I have tried the below options:

1. Replaced the default Magento `.htaccess` file
2. Magmi folder has full permission.

Comment: Try this change in .htaccess
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16982331/3098961 It's related to http://serverfault.com/questions/55323/disable-mod-rewrite-for-subdirectory

Answer (score 1):

Magmi as it comes does not include an index.php file in it's root.  Your server may have a redirect rule that prevents access to the folder if this is the case.

Try accessing the Magmi PHP file directly by going to `http://yourwebsite.com/magmi/web/magmi.php`

If this doesn't work, your Magmi files may not be in the correct location (the root of Magento), or a server configuration is preventing it from loading.  Check your server logs to debug this.